# Alignment of the image to the center of the container, problem with image overflow

Tags: css

I have a problem with aligning the image to the center of the container. The image always overflows and I don't know how to limit the height so that the bottom panel, which has a variable height, is always visible. Attached is an image for visualization

[image: visualization]

Comment: can you show the part of your code.....

Comment: will you please tell exactly what you need to do ? and also post your here

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/stoic-grass-kzru6?file=/index.html

Comment: I need red box on the bottom of page (but his height is variable) and align image center of rest of page